# Well-definedness of the order of a meromorphic differential on an algebraic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry

$\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}$In Serre's *Algebraic Groups and Class Fields*, Ch. II, no. 7, we find the definitions of (i) the *meromorphic differentials* on an algebraic variety $X$ (this is denoted $D_k(F)$ below; Serre calls them *rational differentials*) and (ii) assuming $\dim X=1$, the order of a meromorphic differential form $\omega\in D_k(F)$ at a simple (i.e., non-singular) point $P\in X$ (denoted $v_P(\omega)$ below):

> Recall briefly the general notion of a differential on an algebraic variety $X$:
> First of all, if $F$ is a commutative algebra over a field $k$, we have the module of $k$-differentials of $F$, written $D_k(F)$; it is an $F$-module, endowed with a $k$-linear map
> $$
> d: F \rightarrow D_k(F),
> $$
> satisfying the usual condition $d(x y)=x \cdot d y+y \cdot d x$. The $d x$ for $x \in F$ generate $D_k(F)$ and $D_k(F)$ is the "universal" module with these properties. For more details, see [11], exposé 13 (Cartier).
>
> These remarks apply in particular to the local rings $\mathcal{O}_P$ and to the field of rational functions $F=k(X)$ of an algebraic variety $X$ (of any dimension $r$). Reducing to the affine case, one immediately checks that the $\underline{\Omega}_P=D_k\left(\mathcal{O}_P\right)$ form a coherent algebraic sheaf on $X$; furthermore
> $$
> D_k(F)=D_k\left(\mathcal{O}_P\right) \otimes_{ \mathcal{O}_P} F .
> $$
> If $P$ is a simple point of $X$ and if $t_1, \ldots, t_r$ form a regular system of parameters at $P$, the $d t_i$ form a basis of $D_k\left(\mathcal{O}_P\right)$; this can be seen, for example, by applying thm. 5 of exposé 17 of the Seminar cited above. Thus the sheaf of $\underline{\Omega}_P$ is locally free over the open set of simple points of $X$ (it thus corresponds to a vector bundle which is nothing other than the dual of the tangent space).
>
> Now if we come back to the case of a *curve* satisfying the conditions of no. 1, we see that, in this case, $D_k(F)$ is a vector space of dimension $1$ over $F=k(X)$ and that the sheaf $\overline{\Omega}$ of the $\underline{\Omega}_P$ is a subsheaf of the constant sheaf $D_k(F)$. If $t$ is a local uniformizer at $P$, the differential $dt$ of $t$ is a basis of the $\sO_P$-module $\underline{\Omega}_P$ and it is also a basis of the vector $F$-vector space $D_k(F)$. Thus if $\omega\in D_k(F)$, we can write $\omega=fdt$, with $f\in F$. Then supposing $\omega\neq 0$, we put
> $$
> v_P(\omega)=v_P(f).
> $$
> one sees immediately that this definition is indeed *invariant*, i.e., independent of the choice of $dt$.

I don't understand the very last sentence. How does one prove invariance? Suppose $s\in\sO_P$ is another uniformizer, so that $s=ut$, where $u$ is a unit of $\sO_P$, and that for $\omega\in D_k(F)$, we have $fdt=\omega=gds$, where $f,g\in F$. Why is then $v_P(f)=v_P(g)$? One has $ds=udt+tdu$, but I don't know how to exploit this.

Comment: For reference: it is possible to extend the definition of the order of a meromorphic function to work as well at a singular point of a curve (maybe somehow that of a meromorphic differential too?). More generally, one can define the order of a Cartier divisor on a locally Noetherian scheme at a closed irreducible subset of codimension 1, cf. Görtz, Wedhorn, *Algebraic Geometry I*, 2nd ed., Ch. 11, (11.13) (the definition is equation (11.13.3)). The Stacks Project defines the order of an invertible meromorphic function at a closed irreducible subset of codimension 1, tags 02RJ and 0EMH (3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $\Omega_P$ is generated by $dt$ as an $\mathcal{O}_P$-module, we can write $du=fdt$ for some $f\in\mathcal{O}_P$. Then $ds=(u+tf)dt$, and so the valuation of $u+tf$ is zero, as is the valuation of 1.

Comment: $\def\sO{\mathcal{O}}$One can only infer $0=v_P(1)=v_P(u+tf)$ after showing well-definedness, right? Suppose $fdt=\omega=gds$ and write $s=ut$, where $u$ is a unit in $\sO_P$; and write $du=hdt$, where $h\in\sO_P$. Then we have $ds=(u+th)dt$ and $fdt=gds=g(u+th)dt$; whence $v_P(f)=v_P(g)+v_P(u+th)$. Hence, we just have to show that $0=v_P(u+th)$. But why so?

Comment: Okay, I just understood it: $u+th$ must be a unit in $\mathcal{O}_P$ since otherwise $u=(u+th)-th$ would be a non-unit.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo just use the properties of valuations: $v(u)=0$, $v(th)=v(t)+v(h)\geq 1$, so $v(u+th)=0$ since the definition of a valuation includes $v(a+b)\geq\min(v(a),v(b))$ with equality when the two valuations are different.

Comment: @ElíasGuisadoVillalgordo is there anything else you're looking for here?

Comment: Nope. Just accepted the answer, thanks .